# What's the correct usage of "tell" here?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which sentence is grammatically correct:

> I will tell your consultant.

or

> I will tell to your consultant.

Comment: You could also have `I will tell on your consultant.`

Answer (score 5):

This is correct:

> I will tell your consultant.

The verb *tell* is transitive and takes a direct object that indicates the person that will be spoken to. It is incorrect to add the preposition *to*.

**Edit**: Actually, it's a little more complicated than that. Let me explain.

The verb *tell* is actually *ditransitive*, meaning that it can take both a direct object and an indirect object:

> Let me tell **you** *a story*.

Here the bolded **you** is the "indirect object", and it indicates the person that will hear the story. The italicized *a story* is the "direct object", and it indicates what will be told to the person. When *tell* is used ditransitively, you can optionally take the indirect object and move it to a prepositional phrase with *to*:

> Let me tell *a story* **to you**.

(Almost all ditransitive verbs in English allow you to move the indirect object to a prepositional phrase with *to*.)

However, *tell* can also be used with just a single argument object, and in that case you **never** add the preposition *to*.

> Let me tell you.
>
> *Let me tell to you. [Wrong!]

This is somewhat unusual, since the object of *tell* in this case can be either the indirect object or the direct object. Most ditransitive verbs don't work this way:

> Let me give you some money. [Ditransitive -- OK]
>
> Let me give some money. [Direct object only -- OK]
>
> *Let me give you. [Indirect object only -- Wrong!]
>
> ?Let me give to you. [Indirect object with *to* -- questionable.]

Comment: Actually, I'd say that "Let me give some money" is only possible with a special sense of "give", meaning "give to a charitable cause".

Answer (score 0):

The verb "tell" has both transitive and intransitive usages. The transitive form -- a form that conveys the action of the verb to an object -- is direct. You can tell your consultant a story, or you can tell a story to your consultant. But in either case the action must relate directly to an object or person.

"Telling to someone" therefore sounds like the object is missing.

Comment: No, it's always transitive (apart from a colloquial imperative "Tell!"). But as JSBangs points out, a lone object can be either the direct or indirect object semantically.

Comment: How about "I will not tell" or "a story should show, not tell"?

Comment: OK, I was a bit too restrictive. How about "in its core meaning, 'tell' is always transitive"?

Comment: Who can know for sure? Only time will tell. ;-D