# Does the transitive verb 'tell' require the preposition 'to' when indicating an indirect object?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

The following sentence seems to require the preposition **'to'** after the grammatical object *"he was going away"* in order to indicate the indirect object *"no one"*. What do you think?

> "It struck him that there was really no one, besides his secretary and
> a few business associates, that he felt it was necessary to tell he
> was going away."
>
> Source: Carver, Raymond. 2015. “The Compartment.” In Cathedral.
> Vintage.

Should or could it be:

> It struck him that there was really no one, besides his secretary and
> a few business associates, that he felt it was necessary to tell he
> was going away **to**.

For easier analysis, we can strip these sentences down to:

> *Original*: There was no one that he felt it was necessary to tell he
> was going away.
>
> *Suggested emendation*: There was no one that he felt it was necessary
> to tell he was going away **to**.

Comment: If it helps, the sentence says *there was really no one to tell*. Seems fine as it is.

Comment: No, it's not necessary. _Tell_ does focus on the indirect object (the addressee of _tell_), but it can have a direct object, too. If there is only one object NP, it is an indirect object if it's a human noun, and a direct object if it's an abstract noun. _He told me_ and _He told it/the story_ are both possible. If both objects are present, the Dative alternation is possible: _He told it/the story to me_ and _He told me the story_ are both grammatical, but not *_He told me it_. In the example sentence, the indirect object of _tell_ is the relative pronoun, which is fronted.

Comment: @JohnLawler For all you said, my truncated version of the sentence above still seems to require the preposition.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because arguing is not debating, it's oppositional.

Comment: Adding "to" on the end seems awkward, and because "going" is closer the sentence now can be heard as needing a destination.

Comment: @touchstone Are you seriously suggesting that a brilliant writer like Carver would make a simple grammatical error, and that his editor would fail to spot it? The problem is your lack of knowledge of English grammar, not an error by Carver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct usage of "tell" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/whats-the-correct-usage-of-tell-here)

Comment: "It struck him that there was really no one, besides his secretary and a few business associates, [that he felt it was necessary to tell ____ he was going away". The relativised element is represented by the gap notation ‘____’ functioning as direct object of “tell”, where gap has “no one” as antecedent.  We understand ‘he felt it was necessary to tell no one he was going away”. Perfectly grammatical. Note that if there is only one object in a clause, that object is always a direct object irrespective of the kind of noun it is.

Comment: @BillJ Okay, okay. Just making sure. There have been times when I thought there was a grammatical mistake when in fact there wasn't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That thread was informative, but it falls short of answering my concern. The post you adverted to tells me a rule, but it doesn't tell me that the rule is exhaustive or always in force. I want to be sure there aren't exceptions to the rule under discussion.

Comment: @touchstone What "rule" are you talking about? The sentence as written by the author is fine -- see the analysis in my last comment. Why do you insist on doubting it?

Comment: 'I told them the news' ⇔ 'I told the news to them'.  **BUT** 'I told them that I was going away' = 'I told them I was going away'  (where there is a that-clause, with 'that' present or deleted) does not have a similar transformation. *'I told [that] I was going away to them.' ( * = verboten)

Comment: @BillJ My last comment to you was in regards to what I took to be your sarcastic remark that a brilliant writer like Carver doesn't make mistakes. Now, attending to your later comment parsing the sentence, my doubt is that there isn't merely one object, but two. After all, isn't the male speaker telling *something*? Isn't that something *"he was going away"*? If so, isn't this something the direct object?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do away with the extra baggage first and reduce the sentence to its bare bones to serve our purpose— thus out go *the parenthetical part set off by commas* and *It struck him that.*

Now,

> There was really no one whom he felt it was necessary to tell he was going away.

Note that I've substituted *whom* for *that* just to make sure we're clear here that *that* acts as a relative pronoun in the sentence, and not as a conjunction: *that* could be mistaken for a conjunction also, hence the substitution.

It's clear that the above version of Carver's sentence doesn't warrant any use of **to.** The sentence as reads is a tight one.

Or you could put it like this:

> He felt there was no one [that/whom] it was necessary to tell [that] he was going away.

Again a tight sentence disallowing any intrusion whatsoever.

I think your problem lies with treating *no one* as *indirect object* here. My reasoning is that it's the *real subject* of the sentence and *There is* is only a *dummy.* The transitive verb *tell* takes the clause *[that] he was going away* as its direct object. [The conjunction *that* has been omitted here (*conjunction reduction.*)]

Comment: What is the object of "felt"? Is it "that" (the second, a relative pronoun that has to have a function in its relative clause) or is it the clause "(that) it was necessary … away."? That doesn't add up: two objects?

Comment: @LPH— There's difference between _I **felt** [the soft fur] [of my cat_] and _I **felt** [my cat's fur was great_]. The latter **felt** is used intransitively, as here.

Comment: There is a semantic difference: the meaning is different, we have two verbs; the first means "to sense" (I felt the warm sun), the second means "to think, to believe". The first has nothing to do in my argument. In "I felt my cat's fur was great" you use an informal ellipsis of "that" (I felt that my cat's fur was great) , which means that you are dealing with a subordinate introduced by the conjunction "that", and those subordinates have a unique function, that of direct object of a verb. This verb in the sentence under scrutiny can't be but "feel".

Comment: @user405662 Actually "that" is a subordinator here. The relativised element is represented by the gap notation ‘____’ functioning as object of “tell”, where gap has “no one” as antecedent.  We understand ‘he felt it was necessary to tell no one he was going away”. Perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm mistaken, but did you say that **"no one"** is the *real subject*? Isn't the subject the doer of the verb? And isn't the main verb **"tell"**? If so, then  the subject would be **"he"**, right?

Comment: @touchstone Are you asking about the subject of the main (matrix) clause, i.e. the sentence as a whole, or the subject of the relative clause?

Comment: Of the matrix clause, yes.

Answer (score -5):

In spite of its complexity, it would be nice to salvage this sentence, by means of a slight modification, but I am afraid that nothing will do short of a complete reworking.

You can suppress the adverbial introduced by "besides", and that will make the sentence easier to take in (for the purpose of analysis).

- It struck him that there was really no one, that he felt it was necessary to tell he was going away.

"That" (after the comma) is a relative pronoun and the antecedent is "no one", so that "to feel" has for object "that", which does not correspond to what you are trying to say. Also there is an omitted conjunction after "felt".

You have to construct your sentence differently.

- It struck him that he felt that it was not necessary to tell anyone that he was going away.

If you could replace "that he felt" by "to feel", it would, from a certain point of view, make for a better sentence since you reduce the number of that-clauses; however the verb "to strike" is not compatible with this construction. Also you can change "no one for whom it was necessary to tell" into "not necessary to tell anyone" (needed for the new construction).

- It struck him that he felt that it was not necessary to tell anyone that he was going away.

Finally you can reintroduce the adverbial.

*This way*

- It struck him that he felt that it was not necessary to tell anyone, besides his secretary and a few business associates, that he was going away.

*Or better, I believe, this way (but that is somewhat personal)*

- It struck him that he felt that, besides his secretary and a few business associates, it was not necessary to tell anyone that he was going away.

Comment: It's not my sentence. It's Raymond Carver's (as noted in the quotation). I'm not trying to fix it. I'm trying to ensure my knowledge of English grammar is correct. If not, I'm hoping to learn more.

Comment: @touchstone Still, I don't find it grammatical: the second "that" has to be a relative pronoun (can't be the conjunction), and that makes for nonsense.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. A wonderful faith which is yours!

Comment: @LPH  Of course it's fine. Are you seriously suggesting that a brilliant writer like Carver would make a simple grammatical error, and that his editor would fail to spot it? Nothing needs "salvaging". The sentence is syntactically and semantically perfect.

Comment: @BillJ Are Carver's sentences so sacred as to stand  beyond the rigour of grammatical parsing?

Comment: @LPH The sentence parses fine.

Comment: @BillJ Well, let's leave it at that; as long as I am not being asked for an abjuration of what I believe, I don't mind.